# mysql between two dates index

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I'm selecting Data from a mysql database table.
When i'm searching a specific date, my index is wiorking fine.
When I'm searching data between two dates the index isn't working and the query takes to long.
Has anybody an idea how can i improve the query or the index?

Query A:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM sal_import  
WHERE dateStats>="2011-07-28" AND dateStats<="2011-07-30" GROUP BY f_shop


id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  i   range   dateStats   dateStats   3   (NULL)  7896    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Query B:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM sal_import i 
WHERE dateStats="2011-07-30" GROUP BY f_shop


id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  i   ref dateStats   dateStats   3   const   2182    Using where
```

This is the index of the table:

```
ALTER TABLE sal_import ADD INDEX(dateStats,f_shop);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: when i remove the group by clause, the index is working fine. is it a godd solution to group the values in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sal_import WHERE dateStats BETWEEN '2011-07-28' AND '2011-07-30'
```

Also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: hi, i thought the between function was my problem at first, thats why i changed it to the current query. It means the explain function tells me the same problem on between.

Comment: -1 The reason is that it's the wrong type of index. `BETWEEN` is just syntactical sugar.

Comment: What does it mean "wrong type of index" ? When the index is not multiple, i have the same problem.

Comment: See my answer below. The date column is a secondary index, which means it is not sequentially ordered; thus it can be used for lookups, but not range searches.

Comment: *well it can, but it requires the data to be pieced back together again, rather than reading sequentially from disk. If there are a small number of records the full table scan might be faster than using the secondary index.

Comment: And what is the solution for my problem? Is it better to read the data into a temporary table before?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the date index is non-clustered and as such the data is not sequentially ordered by that key on disk. Your table has a small number of records, so the query optimiser has decided it is quicker to do a full table scan, rather than use the secondary index and piece the records together.

A table can only have one clustered index and this is *usually* the primary key. A date column is generally a valid and sensible column on which to put the clustered index, but it may not be the best use of it; it really depends on how that table is used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131(v=sql.80).aspx

Unfortunately in MySQL a clustered index must be on a unique column and you cannot define a clustered index on a column (apparently); the database chooses that index for you by default. Given this you might not be in luck on this one.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html